# QT in Visual Studios 2008/2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, qt

I installed the SDK for QT for Visual studios. I installed the plugin. I created a simple project in QT Creator with just a dialog.

I then try and import the project into visual studios and get this issue:

```
--- (Import): Generating new project of test.pro file
--- (qmake) : Using: \bin\qmake
--- (qmake) : Working Directory: C:\test\test
--- (qmake) : Arguments: -tp vc "test.pro" -o "test.vcxproj" QMAKE_INCDIR_QT=$(QTDIR)\\include QMAKE_LIBDIR_QT=  QMAKE_LIBDIR=$(QTDIR)\\lib QMAKE_UIC=$(QTDIR)\\bin\\uic.exe QMAKE_MOC=$(QTDIR)\\bin\\moc.exe QMAKE_RCC=$(QTDIR)\\bin\\rcc.exe QMAKE_QMAKE=$(QTDIR)\\bin\\qmake.exe

The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: I got the same thing. Did you ever find out the problem or a work around?

Answer (score 0):

When installing Qt on Windows, you have to make sure you add the Qt library to you environment variables.

This can be done as follows;
Search for *Edit the system environment variables* and click at the button *Environment Variables*.
In the box *System variables* you search for the variable named *Path* and add at the end of the line *;C:\Qt\4.8.0\bin;* if you have installed the latest version of Qt (4.8.0) or type another path to where you have installed Qt.

This should enable Visual Studio to find your libraries.

I hope this helps.